# Accept multiple command-line arguments through ARGV/ARGF

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to get my code to be able to accept multiple log files from command-line input to parse through based on different delimiters as well as accept commands to parse through all the steps of a certain log file.

It currently can only accept one command at a time and the log file it parses through is determined in the code, not the command-line input under the variable `@log_file`:

```
@log_file = "07-07-14 to 07-13-14_debug.log"
@log_levels = ['DEBUG', 'INFO ', 'WARN ', 'ERROR', 'FATAL']

def error_sort
  @log_levels.each do |log_level|
    File.readlines(@log_file).each do |line|
      if (line =~ /<#{log_level}>/ .. line =~ /<(?!#{log_level}).+>/) && line !~ /<(?!#{log_level}).+>/
        File.open("#{log_level}.txt", "a") << line
      end
    end
  end
end

def read_log(step)
  File.readlines(@log_file).each do |line|
    if line.match /Recording dut_serial_number/
      File.open("step_#{step}", "a") << line
    elsif (line =~ /Beginning step ##{step} / .. line =~ /Beginning step #(?!#{step}).+ /) && line !~ /Beginning step #(?!#{step}).+ /
      File.open("step_#{step}", "a") << line
    else
      nil
    end
  end
end

command_line = ARGV[0..1]

ARGV.each do |num|
  if command_line == ["--step", "#{num}"]
    read_log("#{num}".to_i)
  elsif command_line == ["--sort"]
    error_sort
  else
    nil
  end
end
```

Thoughts?

Comment: The way you're using instance variables like `@log_file` and `@log_levels` is a variable-scope code smell. You should use constants, like `LOG_FILE` or `LOG_LEVELS`.

Comment: `File.open("step_#{step}", "a") << line` is very questionable too as I suspect you're opening files and leaving them open, to eventually be cleaned up when the script finally exits. Instead use `File.open("step_#{step}", "a") { |fo| fo << line }` which will automatically close the file when the block exits. You're slowing your IO though, by opening and closing the file repeatedly. You should figure out how to open them, write all the lines, then close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be easily done using a command-line arguments parsing library like OptionParser.

```
require 'optparse'

LOG_LEVELS = ['DEBUG', 'INFO ', 'WARN ', 'ERROR', 'FATAL']

def error_sort(log_file)
  LOG_LEVELS.each do |log_level|
    File.readlines(log_file).each do |line|
      if (line =~ /<#{log_level}>/ .. line =~ /<(?!#{log_level}).+>/) && line !~ /<(?!#{log_level}).+>/
        File.open("#{log_level}.txt", "a") << line
      end
    end
  end
end

def read_log(log_file, step)
  File.readlines(log_file).each do |line|
    if line.match /Recording dut_serial_number/
      File.open("step_#{step}", "a") << line
    elsif (line =~ /Beginning step ##{step} / .. line =~ /Beginning step #(?!#{step}).+ /) && line !~ /Beginning step #(?!#{step}).+ /
      File.open("step_#{step}", "a") << line
    else
      nil
    end
  end
end

options = {}

optparse = OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.on("--sort", "Explain what this option does here.") do
    options[:sort] = true
  end

  opts.on("--step NUM", Integer, "Explain what this option does here.") do |num|
    options[:step] = num  # num is automatically converted to an Integer
  end
end

optparse.parse! # all non-option arguments remain in ARGV

log_file = ARGV[0]

if options[:sort]; error_sort(log_file); end
if options[:step]; read_log(log_file, options[:step]); end
```

More information on OptionParser:

- http://ruby.about.com/od/advancedruby/a/optionparser2.htm
- http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html

**EDIT:**

In order to allow using the same flag twice, e.g. `--step 3 --step 5`, we can change the `:step` entry in our `options` map to be an array of specified numbers, like this:

```
options = {:step => []}

optparse = OptionParser.new do |opts|
  ...

  opts.on("--step NUM", Integer, "Explain what this option does here.") do |num|
    options[:step] << num 
  end
end
```

Then change the semantics of what your program does with the `:step` argument, which is now an array instead of a single number:

```
unless options[:step].empty?
    options[:step].each {|n| read_log(log_file, n)}
end
```

All non-option arguments remain in `ARGV`, so you can enable multiple file processing easily:

```
ARGV.each do |log_file|
  if options[:sort]
    error_sort(log_file)
  end

  unless options[:step].empty?
    options[:step].each {|n| read_log(log_file, n)}
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually had glanced at the OptionParser before but was a little confused on it and this really helped me understand how it works.

Comment: In OptionParser, use `--[no-]sort` for true/false flags. This allows using the negative `--no-sort` standard if the user wants to specify the placeholder but not accidentally trigger sorting. In addition, at that point use `opts.on('--[no-]sort', ...) { |o| options[:sort] = o }` to let OptionParser store true/false.

Comment: I'm receiving an error with the code that's saying "test.rb:35:in `block in <main>': unsupported argument type: Fixnum (ArgumentError)" Apparently it doesn't know how to read Fixnum?

Comment: That's weird... maybe try Integer? Float works according to the documentation, and Float is a subclass of Numeric; Integer is also a subclass of Numeric, so maybe Integer will work. That's just a stab in the dark... As a last resort, you could always convert it manually by changing the next line to `options[:step] = num.to_i`.

Comment: Excellent! I've changed Fixnum to Integer in my answer

Comment: Also, I was attempting to go for the program being up to take multiple commands. As in I could call "--step 3 --step 5" and get it to create files for both of those steps from the given log file or even multiple files like "log_one.log log_two.log --step 3" and throw both the first and second log files into the same step 3 file.

Comment: OK, I see now what you're asking. I've added additional info to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your code needs some refactoring. Besides using OptionParser, your use of `File.open` for appending to the files is inefficient. Meditate on this:

```
LOG_FILE = "07-07-14 to 07-13-14_debug.log"
LOG_LEVELS = ['DEBUG', 'INFO ', 'WARN ', 'ERROR', 'FATAL']

def error_sort
  LOG_LEVELS.each do |log_level|
    File.open("#{log_level}.txt", "a") do |fo|
      File.readlines(LOG_FILE).each do |line|
        if (line =~ /<#{log_level}>/ .. line =~ /<(?!#{log_level}).+>/) && line !~ /<(?!#{log_level}).+>/
          fo << line
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

def read_log(step)
  File.open("step_#{step}", "a") do |fo|
    File.readlines(LOG_FILE).each do |line|
      if line[/Recording dut_serial_number/]
        fo << line
      elsif (line =~ /Beginning step ##{step} / .. line =~ /Beginning step #(?!#{step}).+ /) && line !~ /Beginning step #(?!#{step}).+ /
        fo << line
      else
        ;
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Repeatedly opening and closing a file when appending slows the I/O sub-system by forcing seeks to the end-of-file, buffer flushes before they're full, etc. Instead, open the file as necessary, write to it while processing the same sort of data, then close it to let the system reuse the file handles.